# How to control which packages are installed with setup develop vs. setup install?

Tags: python, setup.py

Creating on a python distribution.  I want my unit tests to be installed for developers, but not for end-users.  In my `setup.py`, I have this:

```
packages=['mypackage', 'test']
```

Here is what I want to happen:

```
python setup.py develop
--> Install 'mypackage' and 'test'
```

and

```
pip install
--> Install 'mypackage', but NOT 'test'
```

How can I control which packages are installed in these different scenarios?

Comment: `pip install -r requirements.txt` for production and `pip install requirements-dev.txt` for develop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this code in setup.py:

```
install_unit_tests = False
for a in sys.argv:
    if a == "test" or a == "develop":
        install_unit_tests = True

if install_unit_tests:
    packages_to_install = ['mypackage','test']
else:
    packages_to_install = ['mypackage']

setup(
    ...
    packages=packages_to_install,
    ...)
```